# What is my mistake in this inheritance?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm trying to create a `square` inheritance class which depends on `polygon` base class. Unfortunately, my inheritance class has an error.

this is my `polygon` class :

```
class Polygon
{
    public int Numberofsides { get; set; }=0
    public Polygon(int numberofsides)
    {
        Numberofsides = numberofsides;
    }
}
```

and this is my `Square` class :

```
class Square : Polygon
{
    public float Size { get; set; }
    public Square (float size)
    {
        Size = size;
        Numberofsides = 4;
    }
}
```

My `Square` class has this error

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'numberofsides' of 'Polygon.Polygon(int)'

I don't understand and know how to solve it.

Comment: Post the _complete_ classes. The code at issue is now missing. Post the outer `class SomeName { ... members ... }`

Comment: your constructor for `Square` isn't calling into it's base class's constructor

Comment: Yes, post the class definitions. Both are missing:  The one for `Square` should be `public class Square: Polygon { }`

Comment: Ok, i edited. you can see it again :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jonesopolis' answer is the solution to fix your error.

However you should not use inheritance in this way. It's the classic problem of: "Should Rectangle inherit from Square or should Square inherit from Recangle" The answer being neither. (This is e.g. discussed here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238176/why-would-square-inheriting-from-rectangle-be-problematic-if-we-override-the-set)

The same holds here. Your Square should not inherit from Polygon. Because if someone gets an object (class instance) of type Polygon he may not expect a restriction to Square. It violates the Liskov Substitution principle:

> Substitutability is a principle in object-oriented programming stating
>   that, in a computer program, if S is a subtype of T, then objects of
>   type T may be replaced with objects of type S (i.e. an object of type
>   T may be substituted with any object of a subtype S) without altering
>   any of the desirable properties of T (correctness, task performed,
>   etc.).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Answer (score 4):

Your square inherits from `Polygon`, but `Polygon` has only one constructor (i assume) and you have to be able to call it every time you create a `Square`:

```
public Square (float size) : base(4)
{
    Size = size;
    //Numberofsides = 4;
}
```

Then you can exclude the assignment to `NumberOfSides` in `Square`, because that will already be given to you via the constructor for `Polygon`

Comment: thank you, my teacher gave me an edited code. He solved my Polygon class like this. But i don't understand, can you explain it for me ?

    class Polygon
    {
        public int Numberofsides { get; set; } 
        public Polygon ()
        {
            Numberofsides = 0;
        }
        public Polygon(int numberofsides)
        {
            Numberofsides = numberofsides;
        }
    }
 can you tell me  why Numberofsides = 0 ??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that your base class, Polygon does not have any parameter-less constructor.  So you must call the constructor of the base class with parameters from the constructor of the derived class.

```
class Polygon
{
    public int Numberofsides { get; set; }
    public Polygon()
    {
        Numberofsides = 0;
    }
    public Polygon(int numberofsides)
    {
        Numberofsides = numberofsides;
    }
}
class Square : Polygon
{
    public float Size { get; set; }
    public Square (float size)
    {
        Size = size;
        Numberofsides = 4;
    }
}
```

Now your Polygon class has a default constructor that doesn't accept any parameters.  That way when you inherit from it in the Square class, it's initially set to 0 so that you may modify it to 4 in the Square class constructor.

Comment: thank you, my teacher gave me an edited code. He solved my Polygon class like this. But i don't understand, can you explain it for me ?
    
    class Polygon
    {
        public int Numberofsides { get; set; } 
        public Polygon ()
        {
            Numberofsides = 0;
        }
        public Polygon(int numberofsides)
        {
            Numberofsides = numberofsides;
        }
    } can you tell me  why Numberofsides = 0 ??

Comment: He did that just to give Numberofsides a value.  That way, when you use that with your original code, and the constructor that accepts no values is called (the one that sets Numberofsides to 0) and it initializes your Numberofsides variable.  

Then you can set the Numberofsides property to the value you want in the Square constructor like this:
public Square (float size)
    {
        Size = size;
        Numberofsides = 4;
    }


Does that make sense?

Comment: but when i make that code: public int Numberofsides {get;set} =0 , it's the same as with my teacher's code. But my code still has problem. Do you know why it is ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no base (or parameterless) constructor in "Polygon" class which can hold the derived constructor's "float" parameter.

To solve:

- Define a parameterless or float parameterized constructor in Polygon

or

- for a dummy solution try cast to int like above

  public Square(float size) : base((int)size)

Comment: thank you, my teacher gave me an edited code. He solved my Polygon class like this. But i don't understand, can you explain it for me ?
    class Polygon
    {
        public int Numberofsides { get; set; } 
        public Polygon ()
        {
            Numberofsides = 0;
        }
        public Polygon(int numberofsides)
        {
            Numberofsides = numberofsides;
        }
    } can you tell me  why Numberofsides = 0 ??

Comment: You defined a parameterless constructor and never assigned anything its inside to the property(Numberofsides). That's why "Numberofsides" has 0 default value. :)

Comment: Also keep in your mind, you derived a class(Shape) from an other class(Polygon), its calling "inheritance". so when you are instantiate an instance from derived class like " Square p = new Square(); " firstly the base class (Polygon) constructor will be called, then your actual derived class(Square) constructor will be called. So what you pass via " : base(X)" code to your base constructor in the derived constructor definition, the base constructor paramater assigned with it.